# In ServiceStack, how can I InitSchema of OrmLiteAuthRepository to a Named connection?

Tags: servicestack

We're using the built in OrmLiteAuthRepository in ServiceStack, which has the InitSchema implementation:

```
public void InitSchema()
{
  this.hasInitSchema = true;
  using (IDbConnection dbConn = this.dbFactory.Open())
  {
    dbConn.CreateTable<TUserAuth>(false);
    dbConn.CreateTable<TUserAuthDetails>(false);
    dbConn.CreateTable<UserAuthRole>(false);
  }
}
```

You can see it always uses the default connection when it calls `this.dbFactory.Open()` but how would you initialize the schema to a named connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This wasn't supported before but is now enabled [from this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/1e86781ccffce2f2427c0e94266ee556065f1c1c) where you can specify the named connection on registration, e.g:

```
container.Register<IAuthRepository>(c => new OrmLiteAuthRepository(
    c.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>(), "MyNamedConnection"));
```

This change is available from v4.0.57+ that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: Legendary! Thanks mythz!